# the onclick event is not set

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, onclick

```
function main() {
    workMenu("leftVerticalMenu");
}

function log(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}

function workMenu(id) {
    var menuContainer = document.getElementById(id).children[0];
    closeListsNodes(menuContainer);
}

function closeListsNodes(container) {
    var object = container.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        var need = object[i].getElementsByTagName("ul");

        for (var j = 0; j < need.length; j++) {
            need[j].style.display = "none";
            need[j].id = i.toString() + j.toString();
            need[j].onclick = function () {
                hideshow(need[j].id);
            };
        }
    }
}

function hideshow(id) {
    var need = document.getElementById(id);

    if (need.style.display == 'none') {
        need.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        need.style.display = 'none';
    }

}
```

This code creates a list in a minimized mode and enters IDs. But the code don't add `onclick event handler`s to html page. I'm tried to use code examples, but not working. How to realize it without using jQuery ?

```
<body onload="main();">
    <div id="leftVerticalMenu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">item 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">item 11</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">item 111</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">item 112</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">item 12</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">item 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">item 21</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">item 22</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I would suggest to call the main() at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Be careful. It has been said that the examples from Google do not work.

Comment: It was trickier than expected. I found the causes: bubbling sequence of events, adding the click event to the wrong node / on the wrong element and so on. Are you still interested in the solution and a more detailed explanation? Please leave a comment and i will add a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses only one loop. If the list item `<li>` element contains no children `<ul>` list, it stops event propagation and prevents collapsing already expanded menu (now it's also IE8/7 compatible):

```js
function closeListsNodes(container) {
    var object = container.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        var need = object[i].getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
        if (need === undefined) {
            object[i].onclick = function(e){
                e = e||window.event;
                if (e.stopPropagation) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                } else {
                    e.cancelBubble = true; // for IE8/7 compatibility, http://blog.patricktresp.de/2012/02/internet-explorer-8-and-all-the-fun-stuff-e-stoppropagation-e-preventdefault-mousedown/
                }
            }
            continue;
        }
        need.style.display = "none";
        need.id = 'list'+i;
        object[i].onclick = (function (need) {
            return function(e){
                hideshow(need.id,e);
            };
        })(need); // create closure here to remember/pass the correct element to hideshow()
    }
}

function hideshow(id, e) {
    e = e||window.event; // for IE8/7
    var need = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        e.cancelBubble = true; // for IE8/7
    }
    if (need.style.display == 'none') {
        need.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        need.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/krTXh/4/ (code)
http://jsfiddle.net/krTXh/4/show (result)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
if (el.addEventListener) {
  need[j].addEventListener('click', function() {hideshow(need[j].id);}, false);  //IE9+ and other browsers
} else if (el.attachEvent)  {
  need[j].attachEvent('onclick', function() {hideshow(need[j].id);}); //earlier than IE 9
}
```

Comment: I have a TypeError: need[j].attachEvent is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function closeListsNodes(container) {
    var object = container.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        var need = object[i].getElementsByTagName("ul");

        for (var j = 0; j < need.length; j++) {
            need[j].style.display = "none";
            need[j].id = i.toString() + j.toString();
            need[j].onclick = function() {
                hideshow(need[j].id);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

or you can replace `onclick` as

```
 need[j].addEventListener('click', function (){hideshow(need[j].id);});
```